# Google Drive for OS sometimes unable to connect (not a problem in latest versions)

Tags: data-synchronization, error, google-apps

> THis is not a problem in the latest versions of Google Drive sync anymore

Sometimes Google drive for OS X turns gray telling it is unable to connect. The only cure is quit and launch again and it immediately starts to work.

The Resume in menu is inactive.

What causes the problem? How to fix it?

[image: Unable to connect]

Comment: Are there any messages mentioning Google Drive in the `system.log` within **Applications > Utilities > Console.app** ?

Comment: The problem was probably fixed by Google. It does not turn gray anymore..

Answer (score 2):

Quitting Google Drive and then restarting the App seems to work

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a MacBook, you are most likely experiencing this error because Google Drive has a tendency to have connection problems when the computer is woken from sleep. I noticed this happening to me on several occasions when I open my computer up in class, particularly when the wifi takes a while to connect.

Although there is not much you can do about the bug itself, I have found that it is much less likely to happen if other internet-connected apps open.

Answer (score 0):

I am a windows user but I experienced the same problem. I was able to solve the problem by changing the settings on the Preferences.

Click the Google drive icon on your task bar then click the settings (three horizontal dots icon), click Preferences, click the Advanced Tab then change Proxy settings to direct connection if you're not using proxy, then change the Bandwidth settings Download rate from **don't limit** to what is appropriate for you, mine was 100 KB/second.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

#### "What causes the problem?"

There's either a bug or an omission of code in the Google Drive macOS app that stops the app from re-connecting after it has lost its connection to Google servers.

#### "How to fix it?"

You can't. The app is obviously supposed to re-connect after losing connection - it's a synchronisation app. You can't help losing your internet connection - your device might go to sleep, or your Wi-Fi might be unstable. All you can do pray they fix the bug in an update. There is no "good" answer here; blame Google for abandoning its broken software (see also: Android File Transfer for Mac).

Comment: Please explain how this answers the original question.

Comment: @fsb "What causes the problem?" It is/was a bug. The app is obviously supposed to re-connect after losing connection. It's a synchronisation app. "How to fix it?" Update and pray they fixed it. Basically, there is no "good" answer and that's Google's fault.

Answer (score 0):

Quitting and re-opening the app works for me. Here is an AppleScript you can use to create a shortcut for your dock (updated for new "Backup and Sync" version of Google Drive).

```
tell application "Backup and Sync"
    quit
end tell

delay 10

tell application "Backup and Sync"
    activate
end tell
```